# Clojure nrepl: 'cider-jack-in returns error: "Spawning child process: Invalid argument"

Tags: process, clojure, cider

Running GNUEmacs 26.3 on Windows 10, trying to set up environment per instructions for 'Clojure for the Brave and True' from here:

https://github.com/flyingmachine/emacs-for-clojure/

I was able to get the packages built and such, looks like it behaves ok.  However, when I start a `lein repl` in the directory and call `M-x cider-jack-in`, I get:

```
Spawning child process: Invalid argument
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Try `M-x cider-connect` if you've already started a REPL via leiningen yourself.

`cider-jack-in` tries to start a repl-server and connect to it. For some reason, this fails, maybe because of the already running REPL, so you might try `cider-jack-in` without starting a REPL manually first.